# Minimum permissions of Team Foundation Background job service account to collection database

Tags: tfs

I inherited an installation of TFS 2015 Update 3 and checked permissions on the Team Foundation Background Job Agent service account are db_owner and TFSExecRole on the TFS collection databases. Are both permissions necessary or db_owner is overkill and just TFSExecRole is needed?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The Team Foundation Background Job Agent service uses the same service account as TFS does, TFSService. To operate correctly, this account requires the following permissions:

- Log on as a service
- Farm Administrators group for any SharePoint Web applications that
  Team Foundation Server uses
- TFSExecRole or both of the following for any databases that Team
  Foundation Server uses:

  - db_owner
  - db_create

I've tested an account with only TFSExecRole to run TFS Background Job Agent service, it works.

Comment: Hi Cece, does not exist db_create permissions at the database level. but db_creator role at the SQL instance level. Even in documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies-tfs#service-accounts-for-team-foundation-server) it refers to db_create database level, which I believe is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

TFS Background Job Agent service uses the TFS Service account. The permissions of db_owner is default assigned when we configure TFS. It is not recommended to alter permissions of these service accounts from defaults.